# Why are there commas before "or even" in the following examples (even though they don't introduce independent clauses)?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I searched for "or even like taking a" on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=9BP&ei=pjbmXLTQLZDQ8wWH9oOAAQ&q=%22or%20even%20like%20taking%20a%20%22&oq=%22or%20even%20like%20taking%20a%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l7.988.988..1052...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.Fu_ZAHZM0xw), and I got results like these:

> Sometimes that work looks a lot like staring blankly at the page, **or
>   even like taking a long walk with the dog.**
>
> The word ethics can sometimes seem overly philosophical, **or even like
>   taking a moral high ground.**

Grammarly's [blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-or/) states that you should add a comma before or if what follows is an independent clause. But as you can see in the examples, what follows aren't independent clauses (almost every result has a comma).

Why was a comma added in these examples?

Note: Because of this, I'm not sure whether to add a comma here:

> He didn't feel dirty, or even like taking a shower.

Comment: I think coordinators like but and or are usually preceded by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the commas are there simply because the writers of those examples did not agree with the guidelines Grammarly cites. And to be frank, I’m with those writers. I probably overuse commas, but (see!) I think my readers appreciate the assistance they provide if reading the material allowed. The pause implied by a comma can help the reader break longer, more complex sentences into more easily manageable chunks.

And that applies to your own example. I prefer your:

> He didn’t feel dirty, or even like taking a shower.

over (your implied):

> He didn’t feel dirty or even like taking a shower.

Bottom line here is that if it’s not negatively impacting comprehension or meaning, including nuance and the like, and may even be enhancing those things, then this is more a matter of style than of hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with tkp.

Essentially, I add commons either where you're technically meant to, or just where I might take a brief pause/breath (when I read the sentence out loud).

The sentences above would technically be correct without the commas, but it feels correct to have a pause at this point in the sentence to make the second part stand out. The author is making a point, in my opinion.